# Is it safe to use a beta library in production?

Tags: android, beta, retrofit2

I am willing to use retrofit 2.0.0-beta3

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

with the basic functionalities of the library , how ever i'm not sure whether for retrofit or generally it is same safe to use a library in beta stage with it's basic functionalities , as long as i tested it and it's working (but with out bench marking).

Comment: Try using stable version.

Comment: what about `compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2')`

Answer (score 4):

> A pre-release of software that is given out to a large group of users
>   to try under real conditions. Beta versions have gone through alpha
>   testing inhouse and are generally fairly close in look, feel and
>   function to the final product; however, design changes often occur as
>   a result.

An early version of a program or application that contains most of the major features, but is not yet complete. Sometimes these versions are released only to a select group of people
So , In my opinion, Its not good to call **Beta** version .

Use **stable version instead beta** .

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2')
```

is secure .

Answer (score 1):

I think in general case, @Amiya is right, but I think in this special case, I would recommend Retrofit 2 beta.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

> You may be curious that is it time to move to Retrofit 2.0 yet? Since it is still in the beta stage so you may want to stay with 1.9 first except you are an early adopter like me, Retrofit 2.0 works pretty great and there is no any bug found yet based on my own experiment.